# Generate duplicate templates with different breadcrumbs when referenced from different toctrees

Tags: python-sphinx, breadcrumbs, tableofcontents, toctree

My document structure looks like this:

```
├── common
│   └── shared.rst
├── foo
│   └── foo.rst
├── index.rst
└── zoo
    └── zoo.rst
```

The generated structure looks like:

```
├── common
│   └── shared.html (breadcrumbs: home -> zoo -> shared)
├── foo
│   └── foo.html
├── index.html
└── zoo
    └── zoo.html
```

My toctree for foo & zoo both look like:

```
.. toctree::
    :includehidden:

    ../common/shared
```

I want 2 different shared.html files to be compiled one with the breadcrumbs looking like `breadcrumbs: home -> zoo -> shared` and the other `breadcrumbs: home -> foo -> shared`. Is this possible with sphinx?

For reference this is my template code for the breadcrumb generation:

```
<section>
  <ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">Home</a></li>
    {% for doc in parents %}
      <li><a href="{{ doc.link|e }}">{{ doc.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if title != 'LaunchKey Documentation' %}
      <li><a href="#" class="active">{{ title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up putting a `shared.rst` in both `/foo` and `/zoo` and used an include to use the shared copy.

```
.. include:: ../common/shared.rst
```